# add html url tag in joomla php function

Tags: php, joomla3.0

i have installed joomla 3 and i have installed leave management    component in my joomla. Its working perfectly. Now i want to    customize the mail function. While changing the code i have some    problem. i want to add HTML URL in message body. Here below the code.

```
       //email function message body

       $body   = "Dear Mr. ".$manager_name.", \n\n You have received a leave request:\n\n From Name:   " .$fromusers_name."\n\n Leave Type:     " .$subject."\n\n From Date:     " .$fromdate."\n\n To Date:            " .$todate."\n\n Message:       " .$message."\n\n  ". ?><a    href="http://intranet/intranet">Click Here</a> <?php ."   " ; // email message body

       If i run this code means my joomla is not running, simply blank page    coming.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$body = "Dear Mr. ".$manager_name. ", \n\n 
You have received a leave request:\n\n 
From Name: " .$fromusers_name. "\n\n 
Leave Type: " .$subject. "\n\n 
From Date: " .$fromdate. "\n\n 
To Date: " .$todate. "\n\n 
Message: " .$message. "\n\n <a href='http://intranet/intranet'>Click Here</a>";
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I got like this only - <a href='http://intranet/intranet'>Click Here</a>